# How to use the same script on multiple game objects in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script `CoinFill` which makes a radial progress bar.

When the FillAmount = 1 I want to reset that specific Image to zero.  I want to be able to use this for multiple `GameObject`s. The problem is that when the first `FillAmount`=1, the penny which speed is faster, you can click on the nickle, which may be at 50% fill and then the penny will reset to 0.  However if the nickle is at 1 it will not reset itself, only the penny will rest.

Image of what I am trying to do:
[image]

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CoinFill : MonoBehaviour {

    public SavingsAccountManager sam;

    public float fillCoinSpeed;
    public Image coinFill;
    public float maxCoinFill = 100f;
    public float minCoinFill = 0f;
    public float currentCoinFill;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        currentCoinFill = minCoinFill;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (currentCoinFill < maxCoinFill)
        {
            currentCoinFill += fillCoinSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        coinFill.fillAmount = currentCoinFill / maxCoinFill;
    }
 //Penny Button
    public void PennyPush()
    {
        if (coinFill.fillAmount == 1)
        {
           sam.savingsAccountAmount += .01f;
           sam.savingsAccountText.text = sam.savingsAccountAmount.ToString("f2");
           currentCoinFill = minCoinFill;
        }

    }

 //Nickle Button
    public void NicklePush()
    {
        if (coinFill.fillAmount == 1)
        {
            sam.savingsAccountAmount += .05f;
            sam.savingsAccountText.text = sam.savingsAccountAmount.ToString("f2");
            currentCoinFill = minCoinFill;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I need to do something with a parent of the Penny or Nickle  or if I should be using a `this` or set up some parent thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have THREE different pennies, A B and C

1) so indeed create the THREE pennies in the scene .. ie, make **three new game objects** and add the graphics or whatever.  be sure to set the name properly on each game object

2) look at A.  **drag your script ON TO A.**

3) look at the inspector variable slots ON THE SCRIPT **actually ON A.**

4) drag A from the hierarchy ON TO THOSE INSPECTOR VARIABLE SLOTS, on A

ie, it's totally **ok to drag an item "on to itself"**.  in other words your variables in the script will refer simply to "that item itself, A"

5) now forget A.  **look only at B**

6) drag the script on to B.  again, drag B "on to itself" to fill the slots

7) now C.  drag the script on to C. again, drag C "on to itself" to fill the slots

at the top of the script (in Awake) or whatever **add this**

Debug.Log("THIS particular script is on " +gameObject.name);

Run. notice you see three of those.

You now have three INDEPENDENT objects with INDEPENDENT scripts!  Enjoy

Comment: Thanks Joe, I initially thought I could do it this way Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: what happens if it is just a string variable ? no dragging

Comment: hi Rifat. don't know what you mean. just try `public string x` and see what happens. you can **type in** a string in the Editor, in Inspector in the slot.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Joe's answer is good, but wanted to add another option to answer the titular question: Since your class derives from Monobehavior,  you can add your script to ANY game object at Run-time with the following code-line.

```
someobject.gameObject.AddComponent<CoinFill>();
```