# How do I access variables on a specific gameobject if multiple games objects use the same script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to to have a radial progress fill up when the progress bar is filled, which allows for the button to be pushed, and the button is pressed it does something and resets the radial progress bar.  I want this to be used multiple times on different Images (the radial progress bar {Green Circle}) and GamesObject (The button).

I currently have multiple GameObjects using the same scripts thanks to the help of this: [how-to-use-the-same-script-on-multiple-game-objects-in-unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591634/how-to-use-the-same-script-on-multiple-game-objects-in-unity/35591973#35591973)

CoinFill Script

```
public class CoinFill : MonoBehaviour {

public Image coinFill;  //This is a green circle

public float fillCoinSpeed;
public float maxCoinFill = 100f;
public float minCoinFill = 0f;
public float currentCoinFill;
public float coinValue;


// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    currentCoinFill = minCoinFill;
}


void Update()
{
    if (currentCoinFill < maxCoinFill)
    {
        currentCoinFill += fillCoinSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    coinFill.fillAmount = currentCoinFill / maxCoinFill;
}
```

Button to reset CoinFill Script

```
public class CoinPush : MonoBehaviour {
 //this is used on a button that looks like a coin and is suppose to reset the green circle Image

 public CoinFill cf;

 OnClick(){
        if (cf.coinFill.fillAmount == maxCoinFill)
        {
        cf.currentCoinFill = cf.minCoinFill;
        }
     }
 }
```

In order to set the image on the CoinFill script I had to make it public.

In order to make the OnClick() public, so I can use it I made a CoinClickManager empty GameObject, but this exposes a public CoinFill Image variable and this is where the script breaks down.

[image]

Here is a picture of the coin and the green circle I want to effect.

[image]

My ultimate goal is to also be able to change the variables on this specific coin and circle as well as the outcomes when the button is pushed via scripts and not the inspector.

Here is the CoinFillManager:

[image]

It makes me drag an image here, but that doesn't access the green circle on the coin.

Comment: So what's the issue here? You just have to drag the 'CoinFill' component into the 'Cf' field on the 'CoinPush' component.

Comment: That is the problem.  I have multiple CoinFill happening.  Each new coin has its own CoinFill

Comment: What object is your 'CoinPush' component attached to?

Comment: In the image above it is attached to the Nickle which is a UI Button.  I will have multiple of these too. So I want the whole system to operate independently.  Above the Nickle I have a Penny (not shown in the image)  they will have different timers and add different amounts.

Comment: So you're saying it is on the same object as where the 'CoinFill' is attached?

Comment: The CoinPush is on the Nickle GameObject.  The CoinFill is on the GreenCircle Image.  I was trying to make the variables from the CoinFill public, so they could be accessed during the CoinPush, so I made a CoinFillManager (this may not be the right thing to do) and attached CoinFill to it.

Comment: you simply DRAG THE CORRECT ONE - it's that simple Tim.

Comment: you can drag to "yourself" if relevant (no problem), you can drag to "another item" (no problem), you can drag to "another item, **which happens to be a parent or child of that item**, (again no problem).   ***JUST DRAG***

Comment: WOOT I got it to work!! WOW.  I just had things in the wrong order.  Dragging is super helpful.  I didn't have to put the OnClick on a different script.  Thanks for the help.